# How can I automagically obtain a detailed script equivalent to a complex `gcc` invocation?

Tags: gcc

It is my understanding that, under the hood, a simple `gcc` invocation such as this:

```
% gcc -o hello hello.c
```

— May actually invoke several separate executables, perhaps hidden inside `gcc` installation. These may be:

- The linker `ld`.
- The assembler `as`.
- An obscure executable `cc1` that is actually a compiler.
- An obscure executable `collect2` with functionality that I find difficult to summarize.
- Any number of other commands.

All of them will be invoked with an outrageous amount of command line parameters and environment variables. However, it is my understanding that the `gcc` executable does nothing by itself, that is, *the whole run of `gcc` is completely described by the commands it runs*, so any single invocation of `gcc` is equivalent to some shell script.

It is sometimes desirable to locate individual commands performed during a run of `gcc`, either to alter and perform them separately, trace a bug in the build process, or simply to document the particulars of a build. Furthermore, it is sometimes demanded that such effort is performed across several build configurations, target architectures, optimization parameters and so on.

A log of operation may be obtained from `gcc` by supplying a parameter `-v`, and redirecting to a file:

```
% gcc -o hello hello.c 2> gcc.log
```

Unfortunately, this method by itself does not provide a script that can readily be executed, altered, version controlled and so on. Rather, the log generated will contain a mixture of actual commands and arbitrary commentary, such as `gcc` version, all in a uniform list. It is then on the operator to manually mark the commentary as such or remove it altogether, in order to, hopefully, obtain a runnable shell script.

How can I *(make `ghc` to)* automagically generate such a script?

Comment: "obscure executable cc1" - that's called "compiler proper". `gcc` is called "compiler driver".

Comment: @yugr Good to know. By chance you can explain the difference between `cc1` and `cc` too?

Comment: `cc` is normally just an alias for `gcc` (on Debian-based systems it can be altered by user to point to different installed gcc versions via `update-alternatives`). Driver takes care of parsing complex input options and using them to set up compilation pipeline (i.e. sequence of programs like `cc1`, `as`, etc. and environments/config files/libraries used by them) to gradually transforms C code to binary.

Answer (score 1):

First of all note that command-line invocations alone are not sufficient - GCC passes additional options via environment variables (`COMPILER_PATH`, `COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS`, etc.) and via temp files which contain compiler options inside them (the latter is AFAIK only used in LTO compilations).

You can easily extract compilation commands via `sed`:

```
$ gcc tmp.c -### 2>&1
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: ...
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.4.0 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/cc1.exe -quiet -Dunix -idirafter /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../lib/../include/w32api -idirafter /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/../lib/../../include/w32api tmp.c -quiet -dumpbase tmp.c "-mtune=generic" "-march=x86-64" -auxbase tmp -o /tmp/cco2cExb.s
...
$ gcc tmp.c -### 2>&1 | sed -ne '/^[A-Z_0-9]\+=/{ s/^\([^=]\+\)=\(.*\)/export \1="\2"/; s/'\''//g; p}; /^ /{p}'
export COLLECT_GCC="gcc"
export COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER="/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/lto-wrapper.exe"
export COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS="-mtune=generic -march=x86-64"
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/cc1.exe -quiet -Dunix -idirafter /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../lib/../include/w32api -idirafter /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/../lib/../../include/w32api tmp.c -quiet -dumpbase tmp.c "-mtune=generic" "-march=x86-64" -auxbase tmp -o /tmp/ccZSUbZx.s
...
```

Comment: Wow, this is quite cryptic. Am I understanding correctly that only lines beginning with a capital lettered variable assignment or a space are selected?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov Yes, exactly.